# What do I need to develop for the Playstation 3?

Tags: porting, playstation3, console

I made a game, and I want to port it to the Playstation 3. What do I need in terms of hardware, money, licenses and such?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you interested in developing for PSN, or as a retail game that people buy in stores?

To develop for PSN, you'll need to start by contacting Sony and becoming a licensed developer.
To develop a retail game, you'll most likely need to contact a publisher who will distribute the game.

In either case, be prepared to demo the game and your company to either Sony or a publisher for approval.

Once you've made this first step, Sony or the publisher will be able to help answer all of your questions regarding getting development hardware, costs, etc.

Good luck.

Comment: Retail, PSN publishing should be another question topic.

Comment: With all the licensing and corporate stuff around consoles, now I can wonder if the gaming industry really deserves its revenue compared to the movie industry... Making a game requires a lot of resources, but I'm not sure it can compete that much with a popular entertainment such as movies.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old thread, I wanna mention an alternative option that has been available for both PlayStation 3 (and later) and Xbox One (and later) from the very beginning: Blu-ray Disc Java, abbreviated BD-J.

These consoles feature a Blu-ray Player, and all Blu-ray players can run JavaME as part of the Blu-ray specification. This means you can actually code games and apps with JavaME, and run it on these game consoles from the very same disc.

So if you're just looking to create some homebrew games for fun, then BD-J is a very attractive option. Because:

- you can run your homebrew games on many gaming consoles from the very same disc
- there's no expensive SDK to buy, you simply code JavaME in whatever IDE you want
- there's no approval process, you just create your own disc and make the ISO downloadable

---

Here's a few YouTube example videos of various BD-J Xlets running on PS3, showing that the platform is quite capable of running homebrew stuff:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_E9VaXywG0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxMpLB_ZsDs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKadWBm9CQA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bC5FV-2AY4

And a few useful links:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javame/bluray-142687.html

http://www.tvwithoutborders.com/

http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=38044.0