# What do I need to program games for the PS3?

Tags: playstation3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I need to develop for the Playstation 3?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59/what-do-i-need-to-develop-for-the-playstation-3)

How can an amateur programmer have access to learn programming on PS3, and test the developments on own PS3? Not only use of CPU but also of GPU.

Comment: You need a development kit from Sony to do this legitimately. These are not cheap and are intended for big AAA games companies.

Comment: Even if the intention is not to make something for selling?

Comment: Yes (unfortunately).

Comment: (Incidentally, the PS3 has a totally uninteresting GPU. You're better off on just about any other platform if you want to play with one.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a development kit from Sony to do this legitimately. These are not cheap and are intended for big AAA games companies.

This is the case regardless of whether you intend to sell what you make.

---

If you just want to get a game on a console, probably the best bet is the Xbox 360, with their [Live Indie Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Live_Indie_Games) program.

See also: [The true cost to get my XNA game on XBox?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19987/the-true-cost-to-get-my-xna-game-on-xbox)

Comment: I was not interested in selling anything, just wanted to learn and test directly on console. I'm attracted to the PS3 by its particular characteristics. But if can't be, won't be :)

Comment: There are some less legal ways to develop on PS3.

Comment: Recently, the Electronic Frontiers Foundation won an [exemption from the Digital Millennium Copyright Act](https://www.eff.org/press/archives/2010/07/26) to allow for legal jailbreaking of smart phones, amongst other things. They are now pushing for this exemption to be expanded to allow for legal jailbreaking of game consoles to allow homebrew development. Having said that, the PS3 homebrew scene does not seem as well organised as, for example, the Wii or Gameboy scene.

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in programming the PS3's Cell processor with its SPUs, you can download the Cell SDK and the simulator for linux [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/power/cell/pkgdownloads.html)

If you have access to a blade-machine you can directly compile it for the CELL and execute it natively. It used to work with old PS3 OS versions too, unfortunetely they removed the ability to install linux.

However, its fun and a great learning experience in case you like low level programming :)